# drupal_http_request , http->data add a string "2000" at randomly lines

Tags: php, csv, stream, drupal-7, http-headers

I have a strange issue, I'm getting a huge CSV file from url with `drupal_http_request`:

```
$http = drupal_http_request($url, array('timeout' => 120.0));
file_put_contents(drupal_realpath('public://').'/httpdata.csv',$http->data);
```

I manage to handle it BUT when I deal with `http->data` I have some string "2000" who breaks lines:

```
2017-01-09,toto,tata,31
2017-01-09,toto,ti
2000
ti,34
2017-01-09,toto,tutu,36
```

[etc..]

When I'm getting csv from browser on direct download and open it into Excel or Notepad++ I didn't have string "2000", so I'm supposing  `drupal_http_request` is guilty but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved my issue replacing drupal_http_request by my own curl request and everything works perfectly!